# CSS: apply background color to first-child of ul li menu

Tags: css, menu

I want to apply red background color to 1st li only i have tried several method but not able
to get what i want:

```
#rightmxmenu > ul > li:first-child > {background-color:#ca212d;}
#rightmxmenu > li:first-child > {background-color:#ca212d;}
```

it does not affect anything

here is my code and css
http://jsfiddle.net/gwdp3/1/

hope any expert can tell me what should i need to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
#rightmxmenu > ul > li:first-child > {
    background-color:#ca212d;
}
```

to this:

```
#rightmxmenu > ul > li:first-child  {
    background-color:#ca212d;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gwdp3/2/)**

You don't need the trailing `>`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the last ">" made it for me.

```
#rightmxmenu > ul > li:first-child { background-color:#ca212d; }
#rightmxmenu > li:first-child { background-color:#ca212d; }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using a class selector in the css and apply it to all your "first" menu items

```
.firstItem
{background-color:#ca212d;}
```

and in HTML use

```
<ul>
<li class ="firstItem"></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
#rightmxmenu ul li:first-child {
background-color:#ca212d;
}
```