# get first occurrence of element in each occurrence of parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry, I have confusing question. This may be duplicate.

`<ul class="slides">
     <li>
        <div class="primary_care_two></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div class="primary_care_two></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
    </li>
     <li>
        <div class="primary_care_two></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
        <div class="app_con"></div>
    </li>
</ul>`

I want to set custom css of first occurance of `class="app_con"` for each `<li>`

Either using jquery/css

Comment: Please vote to close, If you find this is duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using jQuery. You can do  the same using just CSS:

**CSS**

```
li > div:first-child + div{
    /* css properties */
}
```

The selectors which I used in the above code are:

- [Child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) (`>`)
- [First-child pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) (`:first-child`)
- [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (`+`)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.slides li').find('.app_con:first').css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GEJZE/)

Comment: Thanks but, css should be preferable. So css answer could be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is duplicade. Take a look at:

> [CSS: apply background color to first-child of ul li menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250920/css-apply-background-color-to-first-child-of-ul-li-menu)

I think, the best way is use simply native CSS instead of some scripts slowing down website ...

```
ul li div:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Refer to @Mr. Alien

Comment: This won't work, as `first-child` won't respect the class :) you can my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.slides li > :nth-child(2)').css('color', 'red');
```

See it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cScrL/). Or [without jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/cScrL/1/):

```
.slides li > :nth-child(2) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.slides li').find('div:eq(1)').css('color', 'green');
```